# How to include the customly made msg header in cpp code?

Tags: custom-message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed the following tutorial to create my own custom msg.

```
/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv
```

I have a package named test1. I created a msg in this package. After I build the package, the msg header file is located at

```
test1/msg_gen/cpp/include/test1/Num.h
```

I wish to include this in my source code, which is located at test1/src folder. I couldn't use the include

```
#include "msg_gen/cpp/include/test1/Num.h"
```

or

```
#include <test1/Num.h>
```

Could anyone give me a valid header that can include this header file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67272/how-to-include-the-customly-made-msg-header-in-cpp-code?/) by [Bholms](https://answers.ros.org/users/5097/bholms/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2013-07-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
#include "test1/Num.h"
```

---

Originally posted by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) with karma: 471 on 2013-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1